# clarification on inheritance hierarchy for the component class in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, components, jbutton, containers

I am reading `Core Java Volume 1` on Swing. I am having difficulty understanding this paragraph:
Firstly, the author says

> Components can be placed inside containers such as panels.   Container
>   can themselves be put inside  other containers,so the class container
>   extends Component.  Figure 9.8 shows the inheritance hierarchy for
>   Component,

[image]

> Note:   Unfortunately, the inheritance hierarchy is somewhat unclean
>   in two respects.    First,top-level windows, such as JFrame, are
>   subclasses of container and hence   Component, but they cannot be
>   placed  inside other containers. Moreover, JComponent     is a
>   subclass of Container, not Component. Therefore one can add other
>   components into a       JButton (However, those components would not
>   be displayed).

To me, both his statements before and after the picture seems contrary.
I also could not make a clear sense of what the author is trying to say here.
if someone could elaborate with an example or something, that will be useful
Thanks

Comment: This is probably only focusing on one element, but essentially, just because `JFrame` extends from `Frame` which extends from `Window`, which extends from `Container` (which extends from `Component`), you might assume that you can add one `JFrame` to another. But you can't.  These is a restriction within the component to prevent you from doing this. He's highlighting a discrepancy between what the object hierarchy is telling you and what the API can do...so yes, it's contradictive, because it has to be.

Comment: @MadProgrammer: sorry, its not clear to me what you mean here

Comment: Just because `JFrame` extends from `Container` (indirectly), you can not do `new JFrame().add(new JFrame())`. The API won't allow you to do this.  But it will allow you to add other objects that extend from `Container` or `Component`, like `JPanel` for example, you can do `new JFrame().add(new JPanel())`...

Comment: @MadProgrammer: but I could have new JPanel().add(new JPanel()) and same with JComponent right?

Comment: Yes.  This is the point. You can add any type of `Container` or `Component` to a `Container`, except where for anything that is or extends from `Window`, despite the fact that `Window` extends from `Container`...

Answer (score 0):

As @MadProgrammer said in comment, author is highlighting a discrepancy between what the object hierarchy is telling you and what the API can do. JFrame and JDialog are Top Level Containers. If you closely look at the hierarchy, These top level containers does not inherit JComponent. Instead they inherit from AWT Window, which makes these top level containers are special  in swing and make them as heavy weight component. So these heavy weight top level container can not be placed inside another container or component.
All the components that extends JComponents are light weight components. At this point,all light weight components can be placed inside another light weight components or top level containers.

Let me know if i went wrong ... :)